# Adjust height of Boostrap well to total height of children

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height, parent-child

How can I make the height of a Bootstrap well expand as I insert children into it?  I tried to add

```
#myWell{
    overflow: auto;    
}
```

which didn't work.

Comment: What kind of children are you adding ? For example, if you add children that have position: absolute, the height of the parent container will not be adjusted.

Comment: I'm adding Bootstrap row-fluid's and divs with Bootstrap class=span1,span4, etc.

Comment: To add to @Webberig's comment, a container that only has floating children also collapses. I'm not too familiar with Bootstrap, so this is just a guess---how about adding `float: left; width: 100%` to `#myWell`, which will prevent it from collapsing even if it only contains floating children.

Comment: if you're using Bootstrap less files, you could try adding the .clearfix() mixin to the #myWell style...

Comment: @user1114864 please add a solution if you found one